# Search for a string in Specific rows of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have data frame like this :

```
   1   2   3   4   5   
1 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.4 0.8
2 0.6 0.8 0.4 0.7 0.2
3 0.6 0.1 1.8 0.7 0.2
4 0.6 0.7 0.4 0.6 0.1
```

Now , i want to search for the number 0.8 only in first two rows in column no. 5 and 0.2 in rows 3 and 4 in tha same column.

and i have 2000 rows and ofcourse can not do it manually.

Is there a way to do it in R?

Comment: Why would it matter how many rows you have all together when you only want to find values in rows 1 and 2 of column 5 and rows 3 and 4 of column 5?  That's only 4 places to look for 2 numbers.  It suggests you've misworded your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very unclear.

If you want the position of the `.8`, this will do:

```
  d <- matrix(round(runif(50),1), nc=5)
  which(d == .8, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

If you want those with two `.2` just below, in the same column, 
you can use:

```
  # Shift the array
  d1 <- rbind(  d[-1,], rep(0,ncol(d) ) )
  d2 <- rbind( d1[-1,], rep(0,ncol(d1)) )
  which( d == .8 & d1 == .2 & d2 == .2, arr.ind=TRUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

First find all matched positions in matrix.

```
d <- matrix(round(runif(50),1), nc=5)
res_ind <- which(d == .8, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Then restrict results to required rows & columns

```
res_ind[res_ind[,"row"] %in% 1:2 & res_ind[,"col"] %in% 5,]#rows 1-2 & column 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hadley Wickhams 'stringr' package has some functions that can easily do string searches when passed data frames. Something like str_locate(df[1:2,5],"0.8")

Not sure though. I've only just started playing with it for parsing HTML